# Flutter InAppWebView sounds(Audio - JS) not working in iOS real device - Flutter

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter, audio

**AudioPath JS  NOT WORKING IN iOS Real Device**

When I deploy an Android App, the sound ( AudioPath - js ) works, but when I deploy to iOS, does not work.

flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2

iOS device version: 14.7.1

[InAppWebViewGroupOptions options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGwX6.png)

I am not sure what happened, but the flow is.

1.Click in Button( InAppWebView)

2.The Device has to sound like a alert( little ring)

Comment: Did you resolve this error?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, it was a problem with the other team front , the didn have the way to find if the user use device mobile o web ..jeje